# A Mathematical Riddle of Averages

Tags: puzzle, means

The following is an unexpected riddle that originated from the fact that my Calculus teacher enjoys being mean with us, the students:

*The fact that not all students in a class can be above the average grade is proof that, by the same criteria, not all can be below the average grade aswell; so, in a class with $n$ students that can obtain a grade from $0$ to $k$, $k \geqslant 0$, what is the maximum amount of students that can be above/below average?*

Comment: Hint: suppose one person gets $0$ points, and the rest get $1$.

Comment: I wouldn't be posting the riddle if I wanted to solve it myself :)

Comment: You would get plenty of down-votes for that comment if it was possible (but don't worry about it, you'll probably get them for the question instead).

Answer (score 2):

n-1. Say n students get k, one poor unfortunate soul gets 0. The average, which I don't really even need to evaluate, is something between 0 and k. Hence, one below average, everyone else above. Similarly, we can consider the case with n-1 scoring 0, and one over achiever scoring k. By the given statement, we know that it can be no more than n-1, so it is the maximum.

Comment: Nice! Perhaps the people who downvoted this didn´t realize this was just for fun´s sake.

Comment: Theoretically, in this forum, you should want to solve it yourself.  Perhaps that was a reason for the downvote.

Comment: I already had! I just figured i could share it.

Comment: @zickens "I wouldn't be posting the riddle if I wanted to solve it myself"  Step back from that comment and try to interpreted it how it reads as it is typed and not how it reads in your mind.  I'm surprised it wasn't downvoted more.  Do you honestly not see how that the statement is *far* more likely to be interpretted as "I don't want to solve this and I want you to solve it for me" than as "I solved it and thought you might like a go at this"?

Comment: I realized that the moment I got downvoted; sadly misunderstood :/

Comment: Maybe you want to delete the comment then.